# How are Stack Exchange User IDs calculated?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

How are User IDs calculated in the Stack Exchange Network?  On Super User, a user might have an ID of 3568 and on Stack Overflow, might have an ID of 4924...How does this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's assigned by order, I'm 14 on gaming and I registered just when it went live.

The rest are the team and the few that beat me.

Comment: Look at any parent site's user page and sort it by oldest, you'll see that the user numbers are sequential.